# Dispatch sizeToFit to background

Tags: ios, objective-c, grand-central-dispatch

How to dispatch to background thread something from this code

```
-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    [self adjustTextToScreen];
}

-(void)adjustTextToScreen
{
    //label
    [self.detailedCommonLabel sizeToFit];
    //tableV
    CGRect frame = self.detailedCommonTableV.frame;
    frame.size.height = self.detailedCommonTableV.contentSize.height;
    self.detailedCommonTableV.frame = frame;
    self.tableViewHeight.constant = self.detailedCommonTableV.frame.size.height;
    //back scroll height
    [self.detailedCommonScrollV setContentSize:CGSizeMake(self.detailedCommonScrollV.contentSize.width, self.detailedCommonImageSlider.frame.size.height + self.detailedCommonLabel.frame.size.height + self.detailedCommonTableV.frame.size.height + 40)];
}
```

properly, because it takes too long for calculating?

I tried different combinations but the didn't work. `sizeToFit` throws an exception that it must be in main thread. Realm throws some exceptions too.

Comment: ui tasks must run on main thread. you cannot dispatch to background

Comment: You may calculate on background thread, but must update UI on main thread

Comment: You should measure exactly what takes a lot of time in your code, then we can think of some way to improve it. Dispatching something like "sizeToFit" or "setContentSize" is not possible as UI stuff should happen on the main queue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can dispatch to main thread as you are doing some UI stuff on it.

```
 -(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{ 
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self adjustTextToScreen];
    });
}

-(void)adjustTextToScreen
{


        //label
        [self.detailedCommonLabel sizeToFit];
        //tableV
        CGRect frame = self.detailedCommonTableV.frame;
        frame.size.height = self.detailedCommonTableV.contentSize.height;
        self.detailedCommonTableV.frame = frame;
        self.tableViewHeight.constant = self.detailedCommonTableV.frame.size.height;
        //back scroll height
        [self.detailedCommonScrollV setContentSize:CGSizeMake(self.detailedCommonScrollV.contentSize.width, self.detailedCommonImageSlider.frame.size.height + self.detailedCommonLabel.frame.size.height + self.detailedCommonTableV.frame.size.height + 40)];



}
```

Comment: It's already on main thread otherwise my question didn't exist

Comment: That is a bad advice. He asked how to dispatch to a background task because the calculation seems to take a long time and block the UI. Any way "viewDidLayoutSubviews" probably happens ob the main queue anyway.

Comment: In lack of right answers and new year, i'm closing this topic. I think, that this issue can be resolved with activity indicator and white view that appears, while sizeToFit would calculate what it needs.